# \ref and \nameref as one command?

Tags: hyperref

Is there a way to combine the `\ref` and `\nameref` commands into a single command? I want to show the section number before the title. Right now I am doing it like this:

```
\ref{sec:optimizations} \nameref{sec:optimizations}
```

The problem is I am duplicating references. I would rather have it as one command. For example:

```
\myref{sec:optimizations}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\newcommand\myref[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}`?

Comment: Exactly! Just what I needed!

Comment: @jon Perhaps you could make that an answer.

Answer (score 11):

For drivers that do not support line breaks inside links (`dvips`/`pdfmark` driver) you can use the definition that jon has given in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123048/ref-and-nameref-as-one-command#comment275332_123048):

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\ref{#1} \nameref{#1}}
```

or without line break after `\ref`:

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{\ref{#1}~\nameref{#1}}
```

For the other drivers the full expression can be made into one link:

```
\newcommand*{\myref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{\ref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}%
  %\hyperref[{#1}]{\ref*{#1}~\nameref*{#1}}%
}
```

Remarks:

- The star form of `\ref` and `\nameref` prevents nested links. The link is already done by `\hyperref`. The optional argument takes a label name.